# Google Analytics and Marketo RTP Link

Tags: google-analytics, implementation, universal-analytics, marketo

I am trying to link Marketo with Google's Universal Analytics. In the link here (https://docs.marketo.com/display/public/DOCS/Integrate+RTP+with+Google+Universal+Analytics) and they do a great job at telling you the easy things.  The tricky part is implementing the code.

As an example, UA will give you like this: 
var dimensionValue = 'SOME_DIMENSION_VALUE';
ga('set', 'dimension1', dimensionValue);

You can push this with pageview as it is set on session but I have not been able to find what they want you to use as 'dimensionValue.'  Has anyone successfully integrated the two systems in there UA?

Any help will give you instant karma points.

Cheers,
Shaun

Comment: You do not need to set the dimensions yourself, instead you need to enter the numeric index for each dimension in your Marketo admin panel (from the docs: "In the RTP platform, go to Account Settings. .... Turn On the relevant Custom Dimensions and Events to append this data from RTP to Google Universal Analytics.
Enter the Index number of the dimension aligned with the index number in GUA.")

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you don't need to code anything. You just need to assign the relevant dimension to the relevant slot. This is done in the UI under `account-settings`.

If you want to dynamically assign value via GA code then you'll need to use the RTP API so that you can assign the relevant value you want: http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/websites/rtp-get-visitor-data-api/

Another option is using `segment(push to analytics)` or to create an audience under RTP UI.

Hope that helps.

M.